# Protobuf String default value

Tags: c#, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net

On the .proto

```
message ClientInfos 
{   
   optional bytes ProfessionType       = 1 [default = "Doctor"];    
   optional bytes State                = 2 [default = "AZ"];  
}
```

this is the C# code created

```
[global::ProtoBuf.ProtoContract()]
public partial class ClientInfos : global::ProtoBuf.IExtensible
{
    private global::ProtoBuf.IExtension __pbn__extensionData;
    global::ProtoBuf.IExtension global::ProtoBuf.IExtensible.GetExtensionObject(bool createIfMissing)
        => global::ProtoBuf.Extensible.GetExtensionObject(ref __pbn__extensionData, createIfMissing);

    [global::ProtoBuf.ProtoMember(1)]
    [global::System.ComponentModel.DefaultValue(Doctor)]
    public byte[] ProfessionType
    {
        get => __pbn__ProfessionType ?? Doctor;
        set => __pbn__ProfessionType = value;
    }
    public bool ShouldProfessionType() => __pbn__ProfessionType != null;
    public void ResetProfessionType() => __pbn__ProfessionType = null;
    private byte[] __pbn__ProfessionType;

    [global::ProtoBuf.ProtoMember(2)]
    [global::System.ComponentModel.DefaultValue(AZ)]
    public byte[] State
    {
        get => __pbn__State ?? AZ;
        set => __pbn__State = value;
    }
    public bool ShouldSerializeState() => __pbn__State != null;
    public void ResetState() => __pbn__State = null;
    private byte[] __pbn__State;
}
```

There is an error message
on Doctor: the name 'Doctor' does not exist in the current context
Same for AZ

Actually all the string default value have the same error message

I tried to put syntax = "proto2"; but it's fix the issue

Comment: "I tried to put syntax = "proto2"; but it's fix the issue" - you mean specifying proto2 *does* fix the issue? If so, what exactly is the question here? It's not clear to me why you're using a `bytes` field for string data though.

Comment: My bad .... I will change modify the field type